# Layout - one button on top of two buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm inexperienced with Android and working on a layout that is supposed to have a bottom area with 3 buttons displayed this way:

[image]

I managed to almost get it like this, except that depending on the screen, the bottom buttons will be either overlapping each other or too far off. The buttons are supposed to be perfectly aligned below the "APPLY" button, but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's my current code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relapply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/apply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_buttons_carousel"
            android:text="@string/apply_button"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:width="320dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/relapply">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/discard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_buttons_carousel"
            android:text="@string/discard_button"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:width="154dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/save">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_buttons_carousel"
            android:text="@string/save_button"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:width="154dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code for the layout in which the buttons are in. And then everything's inside a linear layout xml test file I made. Any tips on how to improve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have way to much relative layouts, much more than you need.
you can try this layout here (I removed the background and hardcoded the text for demonstration purposes)

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Top Button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/apply"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/discard"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bottom Left Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bottom Right Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can set the layout margins on the outer relative layout (e.g. `android:layout_margin="8dp"`

the layout works like this:
in the top row there is just the top Button. Below it there is a horizontal linear layout containing two buttons with

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

This ensures both buttons span equally horizontal (because they have the same width). If you want the whole layout have a specific width just set the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` from the relative layout to `android:layout_width="320dp"`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I knew it would make sense to work with weights here, but I hadn't had the chance to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_buttons_carousel"
        android:text="@string/apply_button"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/discard"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_buttons_carousel"
            android:text="@string/discard_button"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="0.9" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"></LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_buttons_carousel"
            android:text="@string/save_button"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="0.9" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the output is near about this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following code.....
This is simple and easy.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Apply" />

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:weightSum="2">

             <Button
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:text="Discard" />

             <Button
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:text="Save" />

        </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
```